# Regex to match end of a line in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file like below

```
ophlsfl.</p>
liojljdsf,</p>
rhsdds:</p>
dfds</p>fdfsd;</p>
dfdsfdfsd</p>
```

The last `</p>` indicates the end of that line. How do I check whether there is anything but `.` `line-break` or `>` immediately before the string `</p>` at the end of the line?
If I use `[^\.\r\n>\^\?]</p>` then it also matches `dfds</p>` from the above text but the expected matches are

```
,</p>
:</p>
;</p>
d</p>
```

The `$` symbol is to indicate the end of the file, I think, but how do I check end of a line?

Comment: `dfds</p>` should not match because it is not at the end of a line ?

Comment: yes that is the problem

Comment: `$` can mean end-of-string (default) or end-of-line within a multi-line string (when using the `(?m)` modifier within the regex or compiling the regex using the `RegexOptions.Multiline` flag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try also matching a newline or end of file after the `</p>`:

```
@"[^\.\r\n>\^\?]</p>([\r\n]|$)"
```

Or if you don't want the new line to be part of the match you could use a look-ahead

```
@"[^\.\r\n>\^\?]</p>(?=[\n\r]|$)"
```

Comment: Thanks...BTW, what about starting of a line, like find the starting of the line in which the match occurs?

Comment: You could use a similar strategy: `([\n\r]|^).`, Where you can replace `.` with whatever you want to be at the start of the line

Comment: will it work if there is a match in the very first line of the file?

Comment: @Bumba yes, that is what the `^` is for

Comment: @Bumba Just use `RegexOptions.Multiline` or `(?m)[^.\r\n>^?]</p>$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can I use `^` as the start of a **line** in a file using `(?m)` operator?

Comment: @Bumba See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ed&i=ophlsfl.%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0aliojljdsf%2c%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0arhsdds%3a%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0adfds%3c%2fp%3efdfsd%3b%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0adfdsfdfsd%3c%2fp%3e&o=m), `(?m)^d` only finds `d` at the start of a line. BTW, the answer to your original question is [`(?m)(?<![.\r\n>])</p>\r?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b.%5cr%5cn%3e%5d%29%3c%2fp%3e%5cr%3f%24&i=ophlsfl.%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0aliojljdsf%2c%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0arhsdds%3a%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0adfds%3c%2fp%3efdfsd%3b%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0adfdsfdfsd%3c%2fp%3e&o=m)